# What does it mean when owner is None on an AWS S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

When viewing an object through the AWS S3 console, under owner I see no value. Viewing the object owner attribute on a query of objects indicates the value of owner for these objects is `None`.

An example query that would return this information:

```
[o.owner for o in s3.Bucket(bkt_name).objects.filter(Prefix=filter_pattern)]
```

In the above case, I would see a list returning w/ `None` values, eg:

```
[None, None, ...]
```

These objects were uploaded with ACL set to bucket owner controlled:

```
{"ACL": "bucket-owner-full-control"}
```

My expectation would be that the bucket owner would show up here, not a `None`. What I'd like to understand is what would cause a `None` to appear. Is this a permissions issue in that I am not allowed to see the owner name? I presume all objects must have an owner and thus `None` is not an "actual" option but merely rendered if I am in fact no allowed to see the actual string.